# euclidean division for polynomials with coefficients in noncommutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, noncommutative-algebra

I know that if $R$ is a commutative unitary ring, $f(x), g(x) \in R[x]$, and the leading coefficient of $g$ is a unit in $R$, it is possible to divide $f$ by $g$. My question is: is commutativity of $R$ necessary? I have this doubt, because everywhere the theorem is stated with commutativity as hypothesis, but I'm not able to see where it is used in the proof.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not necessary. As you correctly observed, the usual proof goes through. You have a choice of whether to do left or right division though, i.e., whether you want $f=gq + r$ or $f=q'g +r'$.

More generally, it also works in *(right) skew polynomial rings* of the type $R[x;\sigma,\delta]$ where $\sigma$ is an endomorphism of $R$, $\delta$ is a $\sigma$-derivation, and multiplication is defined by $ax=
x\sigma(a) + \delta(a)$ for $a \in R$. However, now you need to be somewhat careful with regards to left/right division: If you write coefficients on the right (like I do here), the right division (of the type $f=gq+r$) will work. But if $\sigma$ is not surjective, the left division may not work.

I believe most texts, unless they are explicitly concerned with noncommutive rings, simply do not treat polynomial rings over noncommutative rings at all.

Comment: Perfect, thank you (even if I think I'll have to wait for a more advanced course in algebra to understand the second paragraph of your answer)!